# use javascript onclick on a button to switch between two images based on the previous one

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have two images and I want a button which has an onclick event to switch the background image of a div I have, the problem is the first two clicks work but the third click still returns the second image instead of the first. I tried testing it with background color and it works fine, it switches between the two colors.
I would like a javscript only answer also.

Javascipt
(function() {

```
var clickMe = document.getElementById('ray');
var theBody = document.getElementById("container");

var image1 = "url(chidi.png)"
var image2 = "url(chidi2.jpg)"


var colorMe = function() {
    if(theBody.style.backgroundImage == "" || theBody.style.backgroundImage == image2) {
        theBody.style.backgroundImage = image1;
    } else {
        theBody.style.backgroundImage = image2;
    }
    console.log(theBody.style.backgroundImage);
}


ray.onclick = colorMe;
```

}());

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through [the welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: You should show a script of what have you done

Comment: Have to tried to toggle some varible that will be associated with the images? e.g if true, load first image, if flase, load second image, that way you can always change the pictures if you toggle the true,false value.

Comment: @ikeoha In order to receive helpful advise and / or solutions to your problem, it is your responsibility to describe your situation thoroughly, if you can't take the time to do that then don't expect the others to help you. Plus, if you don't do this your question will mostly likely fall into the dumpster soon.

Comment: i have updated it with the script, if anything else is needed please feel free to ask

Comment: @mahlatse I have done that in my script, it works but when the second image shows up and i click on it the first images doesn't come up, instead the second image shows up again

Comment: What is the value of backroundimage before you execute the rest of the colorMe function?

Comment: the backgroundImage doesnt have a value, I tried it in the console and it returned a space, thats why I used theBody.backgroundImage = " ";